# Can a standards-conforming string be longer than SIZE_MAX characters?

Tags: c, string, language-lawyer, c11

I did not find anything in the C11 standard stating that a string could not be longer than `SIZE_MAX` (where `SIZE_MAX` denotes the maximum value of the `size_t` type) characters. E.g. if `size_max` is `long`, and in my implementation there is a `long long` type that is strictly larger than `long`, then I could define and index such a string using a `long long`.

However, this would imply some unusual situations: `strlen`, for instance, might be unable to return the actual size of the string, since the result would be converted into `size_t` at the end, thus a string of length `SIZE_MAX+1` would be reported as having size 0, for instance. Would this, for instance, violate the standard, and thus prevent such strings from existing? For reference, 7.24.6.3 only says that:

> **7.24.6.3 The strlen function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> `#include <string.h>`
>
> `size_t strlen(const char *s);`
>
> **Description**
>
> The strlen function computes the length of the string pointed to by s.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The strlen function returns the number of characters that precede the terminating null character.

Did I miss something, or would this be perfectly valid in (a given standards-conforming implementation of) C11?

Comment: "*then I could allocate [ ...] a string using a long long.*" assuming dynamical allocation, you cannot, as `malloc()` takes a `size_t`.

Comment: The C11 draft "recommends" under 7.19/4: "*The types used for `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` should not have an integer conversion rank
greater than that of `signed long int` unless the implementation supports objects
large enough to make this necessary.*" This indirectly tells as that there would not be an object larger than `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @alk well-noted, I meant "declare" instead of "allocate". I fixed that phrase.

Comment: IMO it's intended that it is not possible to create an object larger than `SIZE_MAX`.  Several parts of the standard are problematic in case of such an object. The C++ standard explicitly says this but the C standard doesn't.

Comment: [Similar discussion from comp.std.c](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/NewGPYEXSCE%5B1-25%5D)

Comment: @anol: "*Declaring*" nitpicking: you want to say "Defining". In C "just" declaring a variable not necessarily allocates memory for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators]:

> 4 When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1. When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array. 102) When applied to an operand that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of bytes in such an object, including internal and trailing padding.
>
> 5 The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type) is size_t, defined in `"stddef.h"` (and other headers).

It follows that the size of any array cannot be more than `size_t` can hold, and thus the size of a string cannot be more than `SIZE_MAX`.

Edit: as of using `calloc`, see [7.22.3.2 The calloc function]:

> The calloc function allocates space for an array of nmemb objects, each of whose size is size. The space is initialized to all bits zero.

It allocates space for an array, but array size must fit into `size_t`, so you can't allocate more than `SIZE_MAX` with calloc. It must return `NULL` if you try so.

Comment: Thar doesn't follow. You can pass two arguments to calloc() which create an object larger than SIZE_MAX and write the string to that. Standard isn't clear on what should happen - ideally calloc() wil return null.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean No, you can't allocate more than `SIZE_MAX` with `calloc`. See edit.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean some argue that it's undefined behaviour to pass such arguments. The standard is not clear.

Comment: The standard is very clear to me: it must return a pointer to the array or `NULL`. Since it's impossible to have such an array, the only option it has is to return `NULL`.

Comment: @IlyaPopov, I think you are mistaken. I suspect the initial intent to distinguish the two arguments to `calloc` is exactly that, to be able to have dynamically allocated arrays that are larger in bytes than expressible by `size_t` (or `int`, `size_t` hadn't been invented at that time).

Comment: @JensGustedt:  "*... to be able to have dynamically allocated arrays that are larger in bytes than expressible by*" `int`, yes. But not larger than `size_t`, as it had not been, as you correctly say, "*invented*" the times when `calloc()` was born.

Comment: "can't allocate more than SIZE_MAX with calloc"  is not correct..    `calloc(sizoef (double), SIZE_MAX)` is fine.  `calloc()` allocates _memory_ for an array.  It does not allocate an array.  Yet that is irrelevant to this answer's correct conclusion about the size of an array object cannot be more than `size_t`. The discussion about `calloc()` is not core to OP's question.  Need only discuss arrays of character type.

Comment: @chux: By the time the Standard was written, implementations existed which treated corner cases in different ways, and code existed for those implementations that relied upon those behaviors.  On a typical 8086 compiler in most modes, individual objects could be up to ~65,520 bytes, but the difference between two character pointers was generally a 16-bit singed integer.  If character pointers p and q identified parts of an object that were more than 32K apart, the sign of p-q would not be particularly meaningful, but adding (p-q) to q would yield p even in the "overflow" cases.

Comment: @chux: A sensible treatment for large objects would be to allow for the possibility that they might exist, but make the use of "sizeof" on such objects a constraint violation, and likewise allow for the possibility that calloc may at its leisure accept objects bigger than size_max, but only if it actually allocates the appropriate amount of storage.

Comment: @supercat The 8086 platform also support a huge pointer model with a 32-bit segment:offset allowing allocation of `calloc(sizeof float, 65000)`.  Yet I think the novel ingenious (and wierd) past ways of pointers, integer, FP, etc are giving way to standard `intN_t`, IEEE binary FP and flat pointer memory.  C's flexibility of the past is no so valued as rigid conformance now.  (Stepping off soapbox now.)

Comment: @chux: I said "most" modes, because while "huge" mode did exist, it was mainly useful for porting code that wasn't performance critical.  Subdividing larger objects into smaller ones would almost always yield better performance than trying to use monolithic objects over 64K.  Further, although C never supported x86 segments particularly well, using a model similar to the old x86 could, with the addition of an "__align8" qualifier, allow many kinds of code to efficiently access up to ~32GiB of storage while retaining the caching performance advantages of 32-bit pointers.

Comment: @chux: IMHO, what C really needs for portability is a means of specifying what types one needs.  Having a means by which a programmer could specify "I need a 32-bit value stored as four characters, LSB first" would not "discriminate" against platforms with 36-bit words, but quite the opposite: it would allow such platforms to make use of code written for other platforms by emulating the needed behaviors using shifts and masking.  Having different types for use when such control is or isn't needed would allow compilers to avoid using inefficient shifting/masking logic except when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Let us put some specs together.

---

> A *string* is a contiguous **sequence of characters** terminated by and including the first null character. C11 §7.1.1 1 (my emphasis)

---

> When `sizeof` is applied ... operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.... .  C11 §6.5.3.4 4
>
> `size_t`
>   which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator; C11 §7.19 2
>
> The limit of `size_t` is `SIZE_MAX`  C11 7.20.3 2

---

If we only use *character array* objects or allocated memory for a *character array*, the longest string size is `SIZE_MAX`.  The maximum return value for `strlen(x_big)` is `SIZE_MAX - 1`.

---

If code is successful with the following, then code has ventured far and in that case, a *string* may be constructed longer than `SIZE_MAX`, but I suspect either `calloc()` will return `NULL` first or  `(char *) ptr` will fail.

```
double *ptr = calloc(SIZE_MAX, sizeof *ptr);
assert(ptr);
char *s_waybig = (char *) ptr;
```